# CFInput - Datefield - Increase Size of Drop Down Calendar

Tags: html, css, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'm trying to control the size of the drop down calendar that comes with "datefield". On a tablet, the calendar seems a bit small. Is there a way to make the drop down calendar bigger? The class "Verd13" only controls the text box size, not the size of the whole calendar.

```
      <cfinput type="datefield" name="bdate" 
          required="true" 
          message="Date Required" 
          value="#todaydate#" 
          class=verd13 
          width="100" >
```

Comment: IIRC, CF uses the [YUI Library](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/) for the calendar.  You will probably have to override one of the YUI CSS classes instead. Use "Inspect Element" in your browser to find out which is the right one, then adjust the width in your `<style>` tags.

Comment: Looked through the CF9 directories - couldn't seem to find what I might need.

Comment: Not the CF directories.  Using your browser, click on the calendar. Use "Inspect Element" to find the appropriate CSS class. Then override it.

Comment: Using CFML since 4.5 I can tell you that using cfinput for anything is not worth the hassle.

Just use a proper framework that you have full control over jqueryui would be just one of many options. The inbuilt UI stuff in coldfusion is garbage.